# Enabling selfsigned HTTPS on Caddy for RocketChat

Tags: ubuntu, rocket.chat, caddy

I installed **Rocket.Chat** on Ubuntu 19.04 using **snaps** according to the official documents.

I need to **enable** **HTTPS** in order to use web hooks and API integration for other systems.

Since this server is in intranet I would like to use selfsigned SSL.

**Snaps** installation comes with **Caddy**, and Caddy has support for built-in selfsigned ssl mode only for 5 days.

I created a selfsigned PEM file but I cannot use it in caddy config file.
It simply won't run.

Browser gets no response from server, for caddy's own cert or HTTP it works fine.

How can I configure my own selfsigned SSL for Caddy in order for Rocket.Chat to use?

Following caddyfile works with 5 days of selfsigned ssl:

```
https://rocket.local
tls self_signed
proxy / localhost:3000 {
  websocket
  transparent
}
```

Change to following and it does not respond:

```
https://rocket.local
tls ../cert.pem ../key.pem
proxy / localhost:3000 {
  websocket
  transparent
}
```

Comment: Can you run caddy with log to get info on why it hangs?  `caddy -log path\to\log.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be to do with using a relative path.  Try using a full path and see if that works

```
https://rocket.local
tls /path/to/cert.pem /path/to/key.pem
proxy / localhost:3000 {
  websocket
  transparent
}
```

Additionally if an option you could use a public domain name and caddy will automatically request a TLS cert from letsencrypt.

On the other point caddy renews self_signed certs on a short basis by design.